# How to determine number of decimal places in prcomp object in R

Tags: r, decimal, pca

I have a "prcomp" object called pcaObj.

When I do class(pcaObj), I get -

```
  [1] "prcomp"
```

When I do str(pcaObj), I get -

```
  List of 5
 $ sdev    : num [1:10] 1.834 1.333 1.079 0.919 0.843 ...
 $ rotation: num [1:10, 1:10] -0.279 0.447 0.271 0.375 0.279 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "Climate" "Diversions" "Economic" "Education" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
 $ center  : Named num [1:10] 63.7 41.9 35.1 38.6 47.6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "Climate" "Diversions" "Economic" "Education" ...
 $ scale   : Named num [1:10] 9.93 13.36 8.44 14.09 11.92 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "Climate" "Diversions" "Economic" "Education" ...
 $ x       : num [1:193, 1:10] -2.77 -1.08 -3.17 -2.13 -3.15 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:193] "1.Albertville.AL" "2.Auburn-Opelika.AL" "3.Cullman.AL" "4.Selma.AL" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "prcomp"
```

I then do summary(pcaObj), and get something like -

```
summary(pcaObj)
Importance of components:
                          PC1    PC2    PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7
Standard deviation     1.8336 1.3328 1.0788 0.91905 0.84344 0.80628 0.75001
Proportion of Variance 0.3362 0.1776 0.1164 0.08447 0.07114 0.06501 0.05625
Cumulative Proportion  0.3362 0.5138 0.6302 0.71469 0.78583 0.85084 0.90709
```

However, I want the values listed from the summary function to be exactly 3 decimals each after the period. I tried things like sprintf("%.3f", summary(unlist(pcaObj))) -

```
[1] "-3.842" "-0.526" "0.012"  "0.307"  "0.516"  "65.800"
```

Please help if you can! I am sorry I was not sure how to reproduce this object in this case!

Edit -

I tried the suggestion of @MrFlick. First, I rewrote the function, and then I called it on my object, but I get errors:

```
getSum <- function (object, ...) 
{
    vars <- object$sdev^2
    vars <- vars/sum(vars)
    importance <- rbind(`Standard deviation` = sprintf("%.3f", summary(object$sdev)), `Proportion of Variance` = sprintf("%.3f", summary(vars)), `Cumulative Proportion` = sprintf("%.3f", summary(cumsum)))
    colnames(importance) <- colnames(object$rotation)
    object$importance <- importance
    class(object) <- "summary.prcomp"
    object
}

getSum(pcaObj)
```

Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

I also tried using round and decimals, but still only some of the columns are changed!:

```
getSum <- function (object, ...) 
{
    vars <- object$sdev^2
    vars <- vars/sum(vars)
    importance <- rbind(`Standard deviation` = object$sdev, `Proportion of Variance` = round(vars, 
        digits = 3), `Cumulative Proportion` = round(cumsum(vars), digits = 3))
    colnames(importance) <- colnames(object$rotation)
    object$importance <- importance
    class(object) <- "summary.prcomp"
    object
}

getSum(pcaObj)

Importance of components:
                         PC1   PC2   PC3    PC4    PC5    PC6   PC7    PC8    PC9   PC10
Standard deviation     1.834 1.333 1.079 0.9191 0.8434 0.8063 0.750 0.6346 0.5623 0.4585
Proportion of Variance 0.336 0.178 0.116 0.0840 0.0710 0.0650 0.056 0.0400 0.0320 0.0210
Cumulative Proportion  0.336 0.514 0.630 0.7150 0.7860 0.8510 0.907 0.9470 0.9790 1.0000
```

As you can see, some of the columns are 3 others are 4 decimals.

Comment: You can try `options(digits = 4)` to set the global option.  Or `print(summary(towns.pca), digits = 4)` might work.  But `sprintf` will convert all the values to character, which you probably don't want

Comment: The rounding is hard-coded into the `summary.prcomp` function (see `getAnywhere(summary.prcomp)`). The `summary()` is just meant to look pretty on screen. If you are using it for some other purpose, better to extract and format the values you want. If you want, you can adapt that code (it's like 8 lines) to your specific needs and create your own summary function.

Comment: It seems like it can be changed for certain values though.  I got a few columns to change in `print(summary(prcomp(mtcars)), digits = 2)`

Comment: Thanks, Richard Scriven. I tried that as well, but only a few columns changed!

Comment: @MrFlick: Thanks. I tried that, and added an edit to show what I did, but still that does not seem to solve the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version of the function you attempted to re-write

```
getSum <- function (object, strf="%.3f", ...) {
    vars <- object$sdev^2
    vars <- vars/sum(vars)
    strf <- rep_len(strf, 3)
    importance <- rbind(
        `Standard deviation` = sprintf(strf[1], object$sdev), 
        `Proportion of Variance` = sprintf(strf[2], vars), 
        `Cumulative Proportion` = sprintf(strf[3], cumsum(vars)))
    colnames(importance) <- colnames(object$rotation)
    object$importance <- noquote(importance)
    class(object) <- "summary.prcomp"
    object
}
```

You just made some mistakes when copying over the calculations, and you added some unnecessary `summary()` calls. I also made is to you could specify the format as a parameter if you like. Now this seems to work

```
px<-prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
getSum(px)

# Importance of components:
#                        PC1   PC2   PC3   PC4  
# Standard deviation     1.575 0.995 0.597 0.416
# Proportion of Variance 0.620 0.247 0.089 0.043
# Cumulative Proportion  0.620 0.868 0.957 1.000
```